# Limit question unknown function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)+f(2x)=0$, prove or disprove with example, that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)=0$ for any function $f(x)$.

f(x) can be a piecewise functions as well.

I tried too disprove it considering several functions but I wasn't able to do so. So I guess that there statement is true but how do we prove it?

Comment: Hint:  find a non-zero function that satisfies $f(2x)=-f(x)$.  A good place to start might be with $\sin x$ since at least $\sin (x+\pi)=-\sin x$.

Comment: We would also require $f(x) \neq 0$ as $x \to 0$ for disproving the statement isn't? I tried all several functions such as (-1)^x *gif(greatest integer function, Signum function, and creating some piecewise function, but for all either the limit doesn't exist or the statement comes out to be true

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sin\left(\pi\log_2(x)\right)$

Comment: @thewitness: define $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @robjohn I mean $x \to 0^{-} $ for f(x) isn't defined.

Comment: @thewitness: Yes, if that were defined, then $\lim\limits_{x\to0}(f(x)+f(2x))=2\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$. It is not necessary to show that the limit exists, just that it is not $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a counterexample, consider the function

$$f(x) = (-1)^n \hspace{14 pt} 2^n \leq |x| < 2^{n+1}$$

for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly $f(x) + f(2x)=0$ on $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ but $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist since the function oscillates infinitely fast as you get closer to $0$.

Comment: The sum of the limits has been assumed to exist in the premise. Does, $\lim_{x \to 0} (f(x) +f(2x))$ exist here?

Comment: @DevashishKaushik It does, as I said $f(x)+f(2x)=0$ everywhere except $0$.

Comment: Wow this solution is really wonderful.